# How I can save an image from the camera in the internal memory?

Tags: android, memory, internal

I have a AVD with Android 4.0.3. I need work with the media store. I worked with folder camera in SDCARD and I put it my images, but I need upload images to folder Camera in the internal memory with the DDMS. However, I don't found any folder to upload my images. I try to take a picture but these are stored in sdcard and I have not found any way to change the settings to save the photos in the internal memory.

How I can save an image from the camera in the internal memory? Is possible make a folder to store images and that images are displayed in the gallery?

Thank you very much.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5252540/416412

Comment: Thank you binny for your answer. I would like simply to create a folder with DDMS and upload the images. I just need to access the images. If this is not possible I make a program with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take an image from camera and capture it on ImageView. Here, I am writing the code to save image of ImageView in internal memory.

```
     Bitmap bm;

     View v=imageView;
     v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
     v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

     String fileName="image.png";
     File file=new File(fileName);

     try 
     {

        FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [official android documentation for Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) shows how you can capture an image and save it in a location in such a way that it is also visible in the gallery.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media) part especially shows how to save your captured image in the most efficient manner (on the SD card).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) you can find information about how to store your picture on internal memory (not the SD card).

Comment: Hello zeiger and thank you for your answer. I read the documentation and in the part of the camara say: Media files created by users such as pictures and videos should be saved to a device's external storage directory (SD Card) to conserve system space and to allow users to access these files without their device.  But, don't say anything about internal storage. I need access to gallery of internal memory, not to an application's private storage.

Comment: Refer to [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to find out about storing your images in internal storage

Comment: Forgive me, but after reading the link I can't find any reference to the internal memory storage allow me to write data outside the application directory itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To save:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```